# Beautifulsoup parsing html line breaks

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse some HTML from a text file. The text is written to a dictionary like so:

```
websites = ["1"]

html_dict = {}

for website_id in websites:
    with codecs.open("{}/final_output/raw_html.txt".format(website_id), encoding="utf8") as out:   
        get_raw_html = out.read().splitlines()
        html_dict.update({website_id:get_raw_html})
```

I parse the HTML from `html_dict = {}` to find texts with the `<p>` tag:

```
scraped = {}

for website_id in html_dict.keys():
    scraped[website_id] = []
    raw_html = html_dict[website_id]
    for i in raw_html:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html.parser')
        scrape_selected_tags = soup.find_all('p')
```

This is what the HTML in `html_dict` looks like:

```
<p>Hey, this should be scraped
but this part gets ignored for some reason.</p>
```

The problem is, BeautifulSoup seems to be considering the line break and ignoring the second line. So when i print out `scrape_selected_tags` the output is...

```
<p>Hey, this should be scraped</p>
```

when I would expect the whole text.

How can I avoid this? I've tried splitting the lines in `html_dict` and it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try another parser, for example lxml?

Comment: You also can drop the second argument of `BeautifulSoup`, and it'll automatically recommend the best parser available on your system.

Comment: @ForceBru This is the recommended parser available.

Comment: Remove `splitlines`?

Comment: @t.m.adam when I do that I get this error `UserWarning: "." looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.`

Answer (score 1):

By calling `splitlines` when you read your html documents you break the tags in a list of strings.
Instead you should read all the html in a string.

```
websites = ["1"]
html_dict = {}

for website_id in websites:
    with codecs.open("{}/final_output/raw_html.txt".format(website_id), encoding="utf8") as out:   
        get_raw_html = out.read()
        html_dict.update({website_id:get_raw_html})
```

Then remove the inner for loop, so you won't iterate over that string.

```
scraped = {}

for website_id in html_dict.keys():
    scraped[website_id] = []
    raw_html = html_dict[website_id]
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    scrape_selected_tags = soup.find_all('p')
```

---

BeautifulSoup can handle newlines inside tags, let me give you an example:

```
html = '''<p>Hey, this should be scraped
but this part gets ignored for some reason.</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

> `[<p>Hey, this should be scraped\nbut this part gets ignored for some reason.</p>]`

But if you split one tag in multiple `BeautifulSoup` objects:

```
html = '''<p>Hey, this should be scraped
but this part gets ignored for some reason.</p>'''

for line in html.splitlines():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find_all('p'))
```

> `[<p>Hey, this should be scraped</p>]`
>   `[]`

Comment: Your method only gives me 8 words from the file, when mine gives 203. I don't think splitlines makes a difference. It's the way the HTML is in the text file.

Comment: Of course it does, it's a completely differend document (unless your file contents don't have newlines)

Comment: What you're failing to understand is that there's a big difference. 
For instance, if we have a text = ' Hello my world my name is foolan'. if we say 
`print(text)'  it will print the whole text if we split it and we look for a portion, in the case 1. It will look into the whole string 2. It will only look at a portion of a portion (since we split it). 
Thank you, Adam, for your great service. Hopefully, all of us can reflect, think and study about from the responses that we've been given and the time that these experts took out for us without compensation.

Comment: Thanks @ElvirMuslic, but i don't do this for the 'fame' (certainly not for the money!), nor i expect gratitude. I just believe in knowledge sharing and i have some time to spare, that's all.

Comment: @t.m.adam You're a decent human being that should be respected. You like many of this community have put in the effort and time to help people. You're an expert in your field, you could be doing anything else but this but you choose to help us. It's a very thoughtful deed.

Comment: As we ask questions and people respond kindly we should learn and study from what they, you, have provided for us for we are in debt for that and should be respectful because of it and even thank you for just tolerating our stupid questions that you (and others) respond to with kindness and virtue. 
Therefore thank you for your service, in the name of all of the community. (i.e. ~36,000  People that you've reached thus far what a great honor!)

Comment: @ElvirMuslic you said it man - reaching out and helping fellow coders - that's a reward on its own! Besides, i got half of my skills from this community, time to give something back.

Comment: It remains a pleasure to learn from yourself and others with great skill, experience, time and devotion for this community, I hope that mods won't dislike our comments as we went outside the rules and had a conversation on something non-related to the problem in hand. Selam (peace be upon you).

Comment: The problem is actually because of bad html that's been scraped. BeautifulSoup intuitively adds a closing </p> tag when it can't see it on a line. So your answer does not help.

Comment: Yes, `BeautifulSoup` will add closing tags in case of malformed html, but it can handle tags that span across multiple lines, as i've demonstrated  in my answer. Besides, splitting html by newlines doesn't make much sense, you should be splitting by tags. Given the sample html and code that you've provided that's the best explanation i can think of, but if you can share more details let me know and i'll take a look.